# What is the supernatural race called the "Uraga"?

Tags: manu-smriti

This is not a duplicate because I'm specifically asking about the Uragas.

"Uragas" are mentioned as a supernatural race in the Manusmriti alongside other celestial/supernatural races like the Daityas, Rakshasas, Kinnaras, etc:

> **[3.196](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199981.html)** - The Barhisads, the sons of Atri, are declared to be the Pitṛs of Daityas, Dānavas, Yakṣas, Gandharvas, **Uragas**, Rākṣasas, Suparṇas and Kinnaras.

Medhatithi does not even comment on what Uragas are.

All the other species are well known.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hindu view of fantastical creatures in scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13938/hindu-view-of-fantastical-creatures-in-scriptures) uraga = naga

Comment: @SK Oh Nagas are Uragas? Where does the answer you linked say that?

Comment: uraga=naga is elementary Sanskrit.  the other question talks about Nagas.

Comment: @SK Can you explain how uraga=naga is based on Sanskrit?

Comment: nothing to explain; Skt is full of synonyms उर-ग [p= 217,2] [L=37199]  m. (fr. उर = उरस् [ Ka1ty. on Pa1n2. 3-2 , 48] and ग , " breast-going ") , a serpent , snake
[L=37200]  a नाग (semi-divine serpent usually represented with a human face) Suparn2. viii , 5 Sus3r. Ragh. &c
[L=37201]  N. of the नक्षत्र आश्लेष (presided over by the नागs)
[L=37202]  lead L.

Comment: @SK Alright fine, but I would like to find an explicit scriptural verse that makes that connection.

Comment: I think you should wait till the afternoon here in india to get more answers.

Comment: i think the sankalasukta that ends with Brahmam sasanam asthaaya kalpadvam iha sannidhim includes Uragas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.swaminarayan.faith/media/3853/vishnu-sahashtra-namavali-stotra-plus-meaninigs.pdf

The phalastuti of the VishnuSahasranama says

> Sasurasura gandharwa, sayakshoraga rahshasam,
>   Jagaddese vartatedam krishnasya sacharacharam
>
> All this world,Which moves and moves not,And which has devas, rakshasas and Gandharwas, And also asuras and nagas,Is with Lord Krishna without fail.

Uraga (literally, one who travels on his chest) is simply translated as Naga.  It is just a synonym of Naga.

Answer (score 0):

[Uragas are Nagas](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm):

> The study of the Bharata is an act of piety. 
>    He that readeth even one foot, with belief, hath 
>    his sins entirely purged away. Herein Devas, Devarshis, and 
>    immaculate Brahmarshis of good deeds, have been spoken of; 
>    and likewise Yakshas and **great Uragas (Nagas)**. Herein also 
>    hath been described the eternal Vasudeva possessing the six 
>    attributes. He is the true and just, the pure 
>    and holy, the eternal Brahma, the supreme soul, the 
>    true constant light, whose divine deeds wise and learned 
>    recount; from whom hath proceeded the non-existent and existent-non-existent 
>    universe with principles of generation and progression, and birth, 
>    death and re-birth. That also hath been treated of 
>    which is called Adhyatma (the superintending spirit of nature) 
>    that partaketh of the attributes of the five elements. 
>    That also hath been described who is purusha being 
>    above such epithets as 'undisplayed' and the like; also 
>    that which the foremost yatis exempt from the common 
>    destiny and endued with the power of meditation and 
>    Tapas behold dwelling in their hearts as a reflected 
>    image in the mirror.